# Driver is not returning any value

Tags: c#, windows, driver, dllimport

Today I started experimenting with [some kernel driver](https://github.com/Zer0Mem0ry/KernelBhop). It is supposed to read/write virtual memory. I have done some basic implementation in C# but it does not return desired values:

```
[Flags]
public enum EIOControlCode : uint
{
    // FILE_DEVICE_UNKNOWN = 0x00000022
    // METHOD_BUFFERED = 0
    IO_READ_REQUEST = (0x00000022 << 16) | (0x0701 << 2) | 0 | (0 << 14),
    IO_WRITE_REQUEST = (0x00000022 << 16) | (0x0702 << 2) | 0 | (0 << 14),
    IO_GET_ID_REQUEST = (0x00000022 << 16) | (0x0703 << 2) | 0 | (0 << 14),
    IO_GET_MODULE_REQUEST = (0x00000022 << 16) | (0x0704 << 2) | 0 | (0 << 14)
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct KERNEL_READ_REQUEST
{
    public ulong ProcessId;

    public ulong Address;
    public ulong Response;
    public ulong Size;

    public KERNEL_READ_REQUEST(ulong _ProcessId, ulong _Address, ulong _Response, ulong _Size)
    {
        ProcessId = _ProcessId;
        Address = _Address;
        Response = _Response;
        Size = _Size;
    }
}

[DllImport("Kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, EntryPoint = "DeviceIoControl")]
public static extern bool DeviceIoControlRead(
    SafeFileHandle hDevice,
    EIOControlCode IoControlCode,
    ref KERNEL_READ_REQUEST InBuffer,
    int nInBufferSize,
    out KERNEL_READ_REQUEST OutBuffer,
    int nOutBufferSize,
    out uint pBytesReturned,
    IntPtr Overlapped
);

KERNEL_READ_REQUEST ReadRequest = new KERNEL_READ_REQUEST();
ReadRequest.ProcessId = ProcessId;
ReadRequest.Address = ReadAddress;
ReadRequest.Size = Size;

if (DeviceIoControlRead(driverHandle, EIOControlCode.IO_READ_REQUEST, ref ReadRequest, 32, out ReadRequest, 32, out Bytes, IntPtr.Zero))
{
    // Returning 0
    return ReadRequest.Response;
}
else
{
    return 0;
}
```

Does anyone has a clue why it is not working?
It is returning the same ReadRequest values as they were initialized.

Thank you.

**EDIT:**
Actually I tried debugging the driver (which works normal through c++ interface) and it turns out that the ReadRequest.Adress value is passed to driver as 0. How it is possible?

**EDIT2:**
I updated struct and some other code:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public struct KERNEL_READ_REQUEST
{
    [FieldOffset(0)] public UInt32 ProcessId;

    [FieldOffset(8)] public UInt32 Address;
    [FieldOffset(16)] public UInt32 Response;
    [FieldOffset(24)] public UInt32 Size;
}
```

Driver output:

[image: screenshot]

The return value is actually the address?

**EDIT3:**
Actually it seems like to work with just `LayoutKind.Sequential` and `UInt32`. Yeeeeey.

Comment: "If the operation fails or is pending, the return value is zero. To get extended error information, call `GetLastError`." The easy way to convert that to a failure condition in C# is `throw new Win32Exception()`. (Supply `SetLastError = true` merely makes it possible to get the error; it does not produce an exception by itself.) It's likely that you'll get nothing more informative than `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER`, but that would still be good to know. Make sure to check other calls that provide error information this way too.

Comment: @JeroenMostert ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND. I am not really sure how can DeviceIoControl return this error. What file? The handle works with diffrent inputs. Just with structs it doesn´t work.

Comment: @JeroenMostert See edit please

Comment: Wrong structure declaration.  An ULONG in C/C++ is a 32-bit type, regardless if the code is compiled to x86 or x64.  So uint in C#.  Fwiw, this type name dates back to the 1980s, back when a long was actually twice as long as an int.  The difference disappeared with the first 32-bit version of Windows.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for quick response. I tried changing all types in struct to UInt32 and it is behaving the same. I have also changed the struct a bit, because I think that the drivers is getting the info shuffled. (Editing the post now)

Comment: Wrong field offsets for a 32-bit field.  Don't help so much.